# ANTLR3 Tree Grammar: loop did not match anything at input 'EOF'

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am trying to create my first ANTLR3 tree grammar, but I keep hitting the same problem. The output of the parser is:

```
$ echo 'foo, bar' | ./run.sh 
foo bar
TreeGrammar.g: node from line 0:0 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input  'EOF'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:29)
```

The output clearly shows that the stage-1 parser results in the right tokens ('foo' and 'bar'). Somehow the stage-2 tree-parser refuses to parse the results from stage-1. Since the code is very basic, it must be some simple, dumb oversight at my part ;-)

Here's my simple test code:

Grammar.g:

```
grammar Grammar;

options {
    output = AST;
}

statement: word (','! word)* EOF!;

word: ID;

ID: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;

WS: (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r')+ { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

TreeGrammar.g:

```
tree grammar TreeGrammar;

options {
    tokenVocab = Grammar;
    ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
    output = template;
}

statement: word+;

word: ID;
```

Driver.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileReader groupFileR = new FileReader("Template.stg" );
        StringTemplateGroup templates = new StringTemplateGroup(groupFileR);
        groupFileR.close();

        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
        GrammarLexer lexer = new GrammarLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        GrammarParser parser = new GrammarParser(tokens);
        GrammarParser.statement_return result = parser.statement();
        CommonTree t = (CommonTree)result.getTree();

        System.out.println(t.toStringTree());

        CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(t);
        nodes.setTokenStream(tokens);
        TreeGrammar walker = new TreeGrammar(nodes);
        walker.setTemplateLib(templates);
        walker.statement();
        TreeGrammar.statement_return r2 = walker.statement();
        StringTemplate output = (StringTemplate) r2.getTemplate();

        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Stringtemplate groups is properly formed, your problem is most probably the fatc you *walk* your AST twice:

```
    walker.statement();
    TreeGrammar.statement_return r2 = walker.statement();
```

E.g., you call `walker.statement()` twice. This is what the (first) error is telling you:

> `TreeGrammar.g: node from line 0:0 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input  'EOF'`

You consume the input once with `walker.statement()` resulting the node stream is at the end (EOF), and then you call `walker.statement()` again and it expects tow walk `word+` again, yet there's only a `EOF` left.